# Having trouble With DevExpress GridControl and importing Excel file

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, import-from-excel

I'm importing a excel file to the **GridControl** in **DevExpress** i have a no problems importing the excel file to the grid control but when i add columns to my **GridControl** then try to import my excel file it overwrites those columns,

i also tried used the **CustomColumnUnBoundData Event** from **GridView** and it seems to work and it won't overwrite the Columns when adding Unbound Columns But when the Button is clicked it creates two columns for some Reason Named **[NAME]** and queries the row values twice.

**SAMPLE VB:**

```
Private Sub SimpleButton2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton2.Click, GridView1.DataSourceChanged
        OFD.ImportMe(GridControl1, TextEdit1)
        view = GridControl1.MainView
        'Dim Columns As GridColumn
        GridColumn1 = GridView1.Columns.AddField("NAME")
        GridColumn1.VisibleIndex = view.Columns.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub GridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData
        Dim Fields() As String = {"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "STOCK", "ORDERED"}

        GridColumn1.VisibleIndex = GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count

            If e.Column.FieldName = Fields(0) AndAlso e.IsGetData Then
                e.Value = e.ListSourceRowIndex
            End If
            ' OFD.Listing(e.ListSourceRowIndex)
        Next
    End Sub
```

i established the connection in a Different Class:

**CLASS VB:**

```
Public Function openMe(ByVal path As TextEdit)

        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.)|*.*"

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            path.Text = ofd.FileName
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function ImportMe(ByVal gc As GridControl, ByVal file As TextEdit)

        Dim Connect As OleDbConnection
        Dim Command As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim con As String

        con = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

        Connect = New OleDbConnection(con)
        Command = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", Connect)
        DD = New DataSet()

        Command.Fill(DD)
        gc.DataSource = DD.Tables(0)
        Connect.Close()
        Return DD
    End Function

    Public Function Listing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal listSource As Integer)
        Dim DR As DataRow = DD.Tables("NAME").Rows(listSource)
        Return DR
    End Function
```

I Apologize for the long post i just don't have any idea what triggers this event so i had to explain it thoroughly. Thanks

Comment: Are the names of your columns and columns from Excel the same?

Answer (score 0):

If your grid has no column when you set its datasouce, the grid will automatically generate the GridColumns.  You can set GridView.OptionsBehavior.AutoPopulateColumns to false to avoid this behavior.